# OSGI bundle logging on Domino server

Tags: logging, osgi, lotus-domino

I deployed an osgi bundle on Domino server and some problem occurs, now I'm trying to locate the problem by check the log, but I cant't find where the log file is, I also tried log4j and configure the properities but still no log file generated. How can I do logging in osgi bundle on domino server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the logs should be in the folder:

```
<Domino Data Dir>\workspace\logs
```

Or if using DOTS (requires OpenSocial add-on to be installed)

```
<Domino Data Dir>\workspace-dots\logs
```

The directory will contain Error and Trace XML files.

Also further logs can be in:

```
<Domino Data Dir>\IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT
```

**Enabling logging.**

To enable your logging for the OSGi HTTP task you edit the following file.

```
<Domino Data Dir>\domino\workspace\.config\rcpinstall.properties
```

For OSGi DOTS task you edit the following file.

```
<Domino Data Dir>\domino\workspace-dots\.config\rcpinstall.properties
```

Both require a restart of the task after modifying.

**What to add to the file**

For the setting you would add the package, level tag and type of logging.

Example (enable full logging on com.my.package):

```
com.my.package.level=FINEST
```

Comment: logs under <Domino Data Dir>\workspace\logs give too little details to solve the problem, I code many logging statments and none of them been displayed. And logs under <Domino Data Dir>\IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT only record xpage errors.

Comment: Have you enabled the logging for bundle? Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, how can I enable the logging for bundle on Domino server